# Расположить строки по возрастанию их длины

Tags: c

Дано несколько строк. Расположить строки по возрастанию их длины и добавить к концу каждого из них, отделив символом «–», их длину.

[github.com/Shmigel/Kep/blob/master/Program_18.c](http://github.com/Shmigel/Kep/blob/master/Program_18.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10

int main(){
  char s1[N], s2[N], s3[N], s[N * 3];
  int i = 1, max, min;

  puts("Enter array1: ");
  fgets(s1,N,stdin);
  puts("Enter array2: ");
  fgets(s2,N,stdin);
  puts("Enter array3: ");
  fgets(s3,N,stdin);

  if( (strlen(s1) < strlen(s2)) && (strlen(s1) < strlen(s3)) ){
    strcat(s,s1);
  }else if( (strlen(s2) < strlen(s1)) && (strlen(s2) < strlen(s3)) ){
    strcat(s,s2);
  }else if( (strlen(s3) < strlen(s1)) && (strlen(s3) < strlen(s2)) ){
    strcat(s,s3);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Все что написал, а дальше не знаю как найти среднюю длину(пробовал но не получалось). Хотел попробовать найти наибольшее а затем среднюю из того что остается, но не знаю как это правильно реализовать

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что нет волшебного слова "и быстро!"... О самостоятельных попытках что-то сделать и речи нет...

Comment: А что составляет проблему? Сортировка или модификация строк?

Comment: @Harry, уже есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy Отозвал свой голос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте теперь сделаем массив указателей на ваши строки.

```
char * arr[3] = { s1, s2, s3 };
```

Теперь нам нужно вызвать для сортировки `qsort`, в которую передать
1. массив `arr`
2. количество элементов в нем 3
3. размер элемента `sizeof(char*)`
4. и функцию сравнения, в которую передаются *адреса* элементов

```
int cmp(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    char * s1 = *(char**)p1;  // p1 - указатель на указатель на char
    char * s2 = *(char**)p2;  // p2 - указатель на указатель на char
    int len1 = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    // Сравниваем длины
    if (len1 > len2) return  1; 
    if (len1 < len2) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Получается что-то вроде

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10


int cmp(const void * p1, const void * p2)
{
    char * s1 = *(char**)p1;
    char * s2 = *(char**)p2;
    int len1 = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    if (len1 > len2) return  1;
    if (len1 < len2) return -1;
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    char s1[N] = "First",
         s2[N] = "Second",
         s3[N] = "One";

    char * arr[3] = { s1, s2, s3 };

    qsort(arr,3,sizeof(char*),cmp);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Ну, а чтоб добавить к каждой строке длину - **при условии, что буфер позволяет разместить там дополнительные символы!** - можно воспользоваться, например, `sprintf` (безопаснее, конечно, `snprintf1 или`sprintf_s`, но это вы уже сами...):

```
void addLen(char* s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    // Пишем, начиная с len-того символа (добавляем к строке)
    sprintf(s+len," - %d",len);
}
```

Т.е. окончание `main` можно записать, например, как

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    addLen(arr[i]);
    printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
}
```

только не забыв увеличить `N` - 10 символов маловато...

Дальше можете делать с *упорядоченным* массивом указателей на строки что угодно - собирать в одну строку, выводить, переписывать - словом, на ваш выбор :)

Если я, конечно, верно понял задачу.

И еще - можно даже сразу создать массив строк типа `char s[N][M];` и сортировать его, а не массив указателей - соответственно изменив передаваемые в `qsort` параметры и компаратор.

Comment: `return len1 - len2;` :-)

Comment: @PinkTux Так - понятнее начинающему.